# Por qué me salta este error al intentar hacer fetch con una api desde react?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

Tengo un error que no he podido solucionar.
Tengo una api que lo que hace es dar una frase de manera aleatoria.

El codigo es el siguiente. Cuando hago click una frase debe aparecer pero en la consola me tira un error 404, no se ha conectado algo y no se que podria ser.
La pregunta es medio tonta pero soy nuevo en esto, si alguien ha pasado por lo mismo me gustria saber la posible solucion.
Dejo el link adjunto.
https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-bhaskara-c18t4x?file=/src/App.js
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El codigo y todo lo relativo a la pregunta, debe estar en la pregunta... si da 404 es que no esta encontrando nada...

Comment: Intenta colocarle el `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`. Esto luego de la propiedad 'method'.

Comment: Es dificil ayudar, si no eres mas claro en tu pregunta y si no presentas el ejemplo con codigo, Puedes poner codigo en stack utiliza las herramientas que dispone para preguntar.